# Posivite Values P For Which a Series Converges

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Consider the following series
$$
\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{(n!)^2}{(Pn)!}
$$

For which positive values of $P$ does the series converges?

Not sure if the Ratio Comparison Test would be useful here:

$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left|\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right| = L
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $P=1$, the series clearly diverges.
For $P \geq 2$, 
\begin{equation}
\bigg| \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n} \bigg| = \frac{n+1}{P [ (Pn+P-1) \ldots (Pn+1) ]} \rightarrow 0 <1 \, \text{ as } \, n \rightarrow \infty.\end{equation}
By Ratio test, the series converges.

Answer (score 0):

Assume $P \in \mathbb{N}$, the convergent condition is that $P \geq 2$.

Observe that: $\dfrac{(n!)^2}{(Pn)!} \leq \dfrac{(n!)^2}{(2n)!} = \dfrac{1\cdot 2\cdot 3...\cdot n}{(n+1)(n+2)\cdot...(n+n)} < \dfrac{1}{(n+1)(n+2)}$. From this you can see that the first series converges. For $P=1$, it diverges.